# Conexão MySQL via IPv6

Tags: mysql, ipv6

Como posso conectar no mysql utilizando IPv6?

Estou usando uma VM(Virtual Machine) Linux Debian e estou tentando me conectar via prompt

Quando tento assim:

```
mysql --host=9999:9999:9999:1:xxx9:x999:2b23:ccab --user=admin --password
```

Ocorre esse erro:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   9999:9999:9999:1:xxx9:x999:2b23:ccab' (101 "Network is unreachable")

Obs.: O IPv6 citado é apenas um exemplo, mas está na mesma estrutura do meu original.

**Editado**

Após habilitar o IPv6 em minha VM, de acordo com um dos comentários, passou a dar este erro:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '9999:9999:9999:1:xxx9:x999:2b23:ccab' (113 "No route to host")

Comment: O serviço IPv6 também é necessário no seu computador.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Habilitei o IPv6 conforme você indicou e agora outro problema ocorre, veja a edição da minha pergunta. O que mais preciso fazer?

Comment: A porta 3306 está aberta no firewall?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sim a porta 3306 está aberta

Comment: Qual é a saída de: `traceroute6 9999:9999:9999:1:xxx9:x999:2b23:ccab` ?

Comment: Fica sendo exibido apenas isso `sendto: Invalid argument
 1 traceroute: wrote 9999:9999:9999:1:xxx9:x999:2b23:ccab 24 chars, ret=-1
 *sendto: Invalid argument
traceroute: wrote 9999:9999:9999:1:xxx9:x999:2b23:ccab 24 chars, ret=-1`

Comment: Será que o endereço IPv6 real começar com `fe80::` ? Esses são [endereços de enlace local](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endere%C3%A7o_de_enlace_local) e exigem um ID de escopo, por exemplo. `fe80::b487:58ad:8d3f:d7b%enp2s1` .

Comment: O ip real começa com 2001:4860.... É um IPv6 gerado pelo Cloud SQL do Google Cloud Platform. Estou tentando acessar o banco do Cloud SQL pelo Computer Engine.